# Unable to open downloaded file at my local machine from azure blob storage

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, blazor-webassembly

I have a .NET Core 6.0 based application. I have written code to download the file from Azure blob storage. It being downloaded but unable to open in Acrobat Reader as a `.pdf` file.

I tried to check what I have in the contents and tried open it in the Notepad++. Then it shows below stuff int he Notepad++.

```
"FileContents": "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",
  "ContentType": "application/octet-stream",
  "FileDownloadName": "db575960-5e24-48dd-33c5-08dc24a66af0",
  "LastModified": null,
  "EntityTag": null,
  "EnableRangeProcessing": false
}
```

This is the API endpoint which sends back the file to client from the blob:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownlaodFile([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequestData request)
{
    var query = getquerystring(request.Url.Query);
    var id = Guid.Parse(query["id"]);
    var fileDataAsArray= await _attachmentService.GetFileStream(id);
    return File(fileDataAsArray, "application/octet-stream", id.ToString());
}
```

Here I am reading it in the Blazor code.

```
var url = "----------------";
var response = await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

if (response is not null)
{
    return response;
}
else
    return new byte[0];
```

This is code which calls the javascript function

```
       var fileData = await _fileService.downloadFile(fileId, IsPTW);

        if (fileData is not null)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("fileDownload", filename, "application/pdf", fileData);
        }
```

and below is Javascript code.

```
        window.fileDownload = (fileName, contentType, fileData) => {
        debugger;

        var bytes = new Uint8Array(fileData);
        var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: contentType });

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
        link.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to open the downloaded file on my local machine from Azure Blob Storage.

The file you are downloading from Azure Blob Storage is in binary format and not in a readable format. To download a PDF file, you need to set the content type to **`application/pdf`**. You can try setting the content type to application/pdf in the API endpoint that sends back the file to the client.

**Code:**

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient _httpClient
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h3>Filedownload</h3>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Increment</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="DownloadFile">Download File</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    private async Task DownloadFile()
    {
        var url = "<Your-blob-url>";
        var fileId = Guid.NewGuid();

        var response = await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync($"{url}?id={fileId}");

        if (response != null)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("fileDownload", $"file_{fileId}.pdf", "application/pdf", response);
        }
    }
}
```

**sample.js**

Here is my JavaScript:

```
window.fileDownload = (fileName, contentType, fileData) => {
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(fileData);
    var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: contentType });

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
    link.remove();
};
```

**Output:**

The above code is executed in my environment, and when I click the download file, it downloads the PDF file from Azure Blob Storage.

[image]

After downloading, I checked from my end, and it opened in Acrobat Reader.

**File:**

[image]